# Python Attribute Error "Battery" object has no attribute "make" - inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, attributes

I'm a Python noob and am having some trouble with some inheritance learning. My code is throwing an attribute error.

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""
    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
       """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
       self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print("\n" + "This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + 
        '-kWh battery.')

    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range based on the battery size."""
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            range = 240
        elif self.battery_size == 85:
            range = 270

    message = self.make + " can go approximately " + str(range)
    message += " miles on a full charge."
    print(message)


class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represents aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize the attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make.title(), model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()

    def fill_gas_tank(self):
        """Electric cars don't have gas tanks."""
        print(self.make + "'s " + "don't need a gas tank.")

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'p90d', '2016')
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

I've played around with the coding and the attributes, but I can't seem to get it to run without an error. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\n\Downloads\inheritance.py", line 184, in 
        my_tesla.battery.get_range()
      File "C:\Users\n\Downloads\inheritance.py", line 158, in get_range
        message = self.make + " can go approximately " + str(range)
    AttributeError: 'Battery' object has no attribute 'make'

Comment: `message = self.make + " can go approximately " + str(range)`. What is `self.make`? And I think those 3 lines are one level unindented.

Answer (score 0):

make is not defined in battery. You need to pass `make` to `Battery`-class:

```
class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""
    def __init__(self, make, battery_size=70):
       """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
       self.make = make
       self.battery_size = battery_size
    ...

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represents aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize the attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make.title(), model, year)
        self.battery = Battery(make.title())

    def fill_gas_tank(self):
        """Electric cars don't have gas tanks."""
        print(self.make + "'s " + "don't need a gas tank.")
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. I don't know how I didn't recognize that. Biggest mistake was putting self.make = make after the default self.battery_size attribute and not before. Many thanks, Maurice!!!